# C# - Send Notification to FCM Firebase fails

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send some notifications to an Android phone using FCM. When debugging with localhost and fiddler, everything seems to work fine. However, when I try to deploy my Webservice to IIS, and replace the localhost with my `IP address/project directory/controller/action` everything starts to fall apart.

My method that my Webservice calls:

```
public bool sendToFCMAndroid(string deviceToken, string message, string title, string type, string notificationId, string postingId)
{
    List<dynamic> errorList = new List<dynamic>();            
    var data = new
    {
        to = deviceToken,
        notification = new
        {
            body = message,
            title = title
        },
        data = new
        {
            type = type,
            notificationId = notificationId,
            postingId = postingId
        },
        priority = "high"
    };
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest tRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlFCM"]));
        tRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        tRequest.Method = "POST";

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        Byte[] byteArray = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(json);

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["androidFCMLegacyKey"]));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["androidFCMSenderId"]));
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream newStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        WebResponse response = tRequest.GetResponse();              
       // Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);              
        newStream = response.GetResponseStream();                
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);
        FCMResponse jsonResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FCMResponse>(sr.ReadToEnd());                                         
        if (jsonResp.failure >= 1) errorList.Add(sr.ReadToEnd()); //check if got failures in json resp              

        //close everything use.
        sr.Close();
        response.Close();
        newStream.Close();               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorList.Add((ex.Message));
    }
    return (errorList.Count() == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

It always seems to return false whenever I call the Webservice by ip/project-folder, so I suspect that either an exception happened, or FCM returned me a FAIL.

EDIT: I've found a lead, after returning the error message itself, it showed `The operation has timed out`. So my hunch that an exception was triggered during run-time. Now the question is that why does it time out when I try to send to FCM during run-time and not debug time?

EDIT2: I tried returning the entire exception class as JSON and these are the two different types of results I get

1. [Timeout exception](http://pastebin.com/iKuyAgCM)
2. [Cannot connect to remote server exception](http://pastebin.com/qt82PuWM)

These two seem to occur at this particular line, weird.

```
Line 206: Stream newStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
Line 207: newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Comment: Hi. It's hard to comment about what might be the cause. There isn't hardly any detail as to where it's coming from. Is there a chance that you'd be able to get the exact error response (if it is from FCM)?

Comment: It just struck me the idea to jsonify the entire exceptions that it throws during run-time when calling it via IIS instead of just the ex.Message. I'll get back to the office on Monday and try it out. Probably will shed some extra light on this matter

Comment: Hi @AL. I posted an update, take a look if that helps.

Comment: Hi Kei. I don't think this is an issue with FCM. Basing from the responses, it seems there is an issue with the connection itself. Have you tried testing this out in different machines, using different connections? See if it occurs from there?

Comment: Too bad I can only try this in the network that my school sets up. I can probably try it out with a test project at home but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: The connection is within your School? Then there is a possibility that the connection with FCM is being blocked. Have you seen the note [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#http-request)? -- "*If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with FCM in order for your Firebase Cloud Messaging client apps to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. FCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230.*"

Comment: Weird thing is, Everything works fine when I use `http:/localhost` and not when I deploy it to IIS `http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/iis-sub-directory/`